# How To Secure SQL Server Database On Client Machine?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I Just Completed My Window Application,In Which I Use SQL Server 2008 as Back-End.
I Install My App With Database In Client Machine.
But Problem Is That My Client Can Also See My Database Using Sql Server Mangement Studio.
I Want to Prevent Client To See Database.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's the entire purpose of a database server. For any authenticated client to be able to connect to the server. That client may be your application or any other application - Management Studio being one of them.

You can either host your database server anywhere else and set up SQL server to only accept connections from your web application's server. But anyone that knows the IP, instance, and has the proper credentials can connect anyway from that server.

Or you can set up a user on SQL server for your application and configure your application to use that user. Now only the database administrator and that user can access that database.

But anyone that browses your application's configuration files will be able to pull the credentials anyway from there. Unless you are using integrated security, in which case the user your application runs under will be the only one to have access - assuming you grant that Windows user access to the database of course.

I guess the real question is, why are you trying to prevent someone from directly accessing the database?

Comment: Thanks agarhy for your quick response.i want to only one credential that i have to access the database using sql server management studio.the reason of that type of security to prevent my database side logic like stored procedure,views etc.

Comment: @SagarSavsani Securing your database should be about protecting your data. Stored procedures usually operate on your data and are worthless without it. You'll need to choose a method I provided in my answer. Bottom line is, you are using a database server and all authenticated user will/should be able to access it.